# directory to be published not found error yii2

Tags: yii2, bower

Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException

```
The file or directory to be published does not 
exist: C:\xampp\htdocs\cult\vendor\bower/jquery-ui
```

I am getting this error. 
I started with downloading yii's basic template. Then installed composer and ran the command to install jui (require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui) using composer.The installation did succeed without errors in command prompt, but got this error. Tried all fixes available. i have developed the application completely, stuck with the need to implement a date-picker.

Comment: You don't provide enough information.

Comment: @robsch Can you please tell me what is the information needed? I am pretty new to composer. not very familiar with stuff. Quite confused here. :(

Comment: Provide the working dir, the commands you have entered, the output, any further details that could help to answer.

Comment: i started with downloading basic yii2 application template. using xampp for windows. root folder C:\xampp\htdocs\cult. composer commands used : composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui

Comment: Sorry... but please update your question, don't chat! SO is only helpful if we have questions and answers that are as clear as possible. You have downloaded Yii's basic template manually?

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 is very simple to install, follow the steps given in documentation.

[To install via composer](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-via-composer)

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.3"
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic
```

given the discription in doc

> The first command installs the composer asset plugin which allows managing bower and npm package dependencies through Composer. You only need to run this command once for all. The second command installs Yii in a directory named basic. You can choose a different directory name if you want.

Comment: This answer is a bit old, best to keep the asset plugin at the most stable edge since new issues will arise which they may fix.